# Convert date from Spanish to English

Tags: c#, asp.net

Current culture of my application is set to Spanish but i need to convert my date to English in order to perform database operations.

currently date is coming in this format: "Dic 13, 2017"

I need to convert this to : "Dec 13, 2017"

what i have tried until now

```
var input = objDMSampleA.RequestDateFrom;
var format = "MMM dd, yyyy";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));

var result = dt.ToString(format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

but the ParseExact gives error that

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: It appears that `Dic. 13, 2017` works. I know this doesn't help, much, but it's something to go on.

Comment: Above code works fine, you need to check the value of `RequestDateFrom`.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Please prove your claim.

Comment: @MAK please see: https://ibb.co/kKjZYS

Comment: @FaizanRabbani and what if you initialize your culture like this: `new CultureInfo("es-ES", false);`? Will it still work fine?

Comment: @Evk It still does.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani and what `new CultureInfo("es-ES").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames` dispay? Are there dots in month names?

Comment: @Evk no dots in month names.

Comment: @Evk screenshot: https://ibb.co/m558tS

Comment: @FaizanRabbani so that means on some machines they do have dots and on some do not. Probably depends on OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Short" month names for given culture are stored in `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames`. For `es-ES` culture those names might have dot in the end (for example: "dic." instead of "dic"). For that reason, parsing your string fails - "Dic" doesn't have that dot.

To fix this, one way is to modify those names:

```
var esCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
var monthNames = esCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
for (int i = 0; i < monthNames.Length; i++) {
    monthNames[i] = monthNames[i].TrimEnd('.');
}
esCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = monthNames;
monthNames = esCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames;
for (int i = 0; i < monthNames.Length; i++)
{
    monthNames[i] = monthNames[i].TrimEnd('.');
}
esCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = monthNames;
```

Then your code will work as expected:

```
var input = "Dic 13, 2017";
var format = "MMM dd, yyyy";            
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, esCulture);
var result = dt.ToString(format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

It's better to store modified culture in some static field and reuse it, instead of creating it and changing every time.

If you want to modify current culture for all threads, use

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = esCulture;
```

though I won't recommend doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question where should I performs the operation you have mentioned so that it becomes a part of my current culture and keeps working through out  the application during the current session?
should I do it  when I am setting 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(strCultureName);

Comment: @MAK I honestly suggest you to not do that, and instead store this modified culture in static field and use when necessary. But if you want - you can modify current culture for all threads this way: `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = esCulture;` (somewhere at startup of your application). Then you can parse with `var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`