# How to convert a date from Spanish to English Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
var a = new Date('dic 30, 2021').toLocaleString("en-US", {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric"
});
```

--> returns 'Invalid Date'

I want to do this in Javascript

Comment: This could be the solution you are looking for - [Convert Date from Spanish to English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249213/convert-date-from-spanish-to-english)

Comment: No @TylerDurden  the link you shared is for c#, I want to achieve it in Javascript

Comment: Use [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that new Date(string) give us a date object we need the string was in the way yyyy-MM-dd. So you need make a "trasform" function, some like

```
  spaToDate(datespa:string)
  {
    const part=datespa.replace(',','').split(' ')
    return new Date(+part[2],
      ['ene','feb','mar','abr','may','jun','jul','ago',
       'sep','oct','nov','dic'].indexOf(part[0]),
      +part[1]
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `Date` class `dic` is not a valid month name, you need to change it to `dec`,

[image]

vs

[image]